# Posicionar un radio button con imagen al lado del otro dentro de modal

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

No estoy pudiendo resolver el problema en el que aparece un `radiobutton` debajo del otro. **Quiero colocarlo a la derecha del primero dentro del modal.**

Así me aparece:

[image: Imagen con disposición de elementos incorrecta]

Y acá está el HTML de esa parte:

```
<div class="cc-selector">

        <input checked="checked" id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />

        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa">

              <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/img/plantilla/efectivo.png" class="img-responsive">

        </label>

        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />

        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard" for="mastercard">

              <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/img/plantilla/payu.png" class="img-responsive">   

        </label>

</div>
```

Sé que por `CSS` podría hacerlo dando `position: relative` y modificarlo como quiera, pero tengo entendido que directamente por `HTML` se tiene que poder también.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es seccionar tu `div` en **columnas** de la siguiente forma

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input checked="checked" id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
      TU IMAGEN
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
      OTRA IMAGEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap tiene una definición en donde cada div equivale a 12 columnas, las cuales puedes seccionar mediante la clase **[col](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)**; en este caso sólo necesitas partir tu div en 2 que correspondería a un col-6 (la especificación de `md`, `sm`, `lg` sirve para la resolución de cada dispositivo)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Me solucionó el problema

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando el sistema grid de bootstrap.

Solo tienes poner cada imagen dentro de un col-6 para que asi tome el 50% del ancho:

```
<div class="cc-selector">
    <div class='row'>

        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <input checked="checked" id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
            <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa">
                  <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/img/plantilla/efectivo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
            <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard" for="mastercard">
                  <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/img/plantilla/payu.png" class="img-responsive">   
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me han respondido con el mismo concepto minutos antes de tu respuesta, por eso la coloqué como correcta.